# How to use a remote database in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to upload an application Laravel to an FTP server, the application already works but the database does not, is that the database is mounted on another server, and I use ping and working properly, I hope your help, thanks in advance.

This my file configuration:

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '198.168.169.151',
        'port' => '2222',
        'database'  => 'Radec_Apps',
        'username'  => 'radec_user',
        'password'  => 'Mkn!',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

I need to configure something else?

Comment: You must make sure that the MySQL server accepts remote connections, check with the mysql command on your terminal or with a GUI tool.

Answer (score 0):

**Granting Access**

Granting access to a user from a remote host is fairly simple and can be accomplished from just a few steps. First you will need to login to your MySQL server as the root user. You can do this by typing the following command:

**mysql -u root -p**

This will prompt you for your MySQL root password.

Once you are logged into MySQL you need to issue the GRANT command that will enable access for your remote user. In this example we will be creating a brand new user (fooUser) that will have full access to the fooDatabase database.

Keep in mind that this statement is not complete and will need some items changed. Please change 1.2.3.4 to the IP address that we obtained above. You will also need to change my_password with the password that you would like to use for fooUser.

mysql> GRANT ALL ON fooDatabase.* TO fooUser@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';

This statement will grant ALL permissions to the newly created user fooUser with a password of 'my_password' when they connect from the IP address 1.2.3.4.

Testing Remotely

Now you can test your connection remotely. You can access your MySQL server from another Linux server:

## mysql -u fooUser -p -h 44.55.66.77

Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 17
Server version: 5.0.45 Source distribution

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql> _

Note that the IP of our MySQL server is 44.55.66.77 in this example.

@ref: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely

you may need to change the my.cnf to change the BIND ip address.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, yes the remote conections are active:  mysql -u radec_user -p -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx